# Trigger doesn't working in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have a table called `Reading`, there is a column call `ReaderID` to specify the reading is read by who. Now I want to add a trigger so when adding a new row in table `Reading`, always check if the reader has already read 5 times. If so, don't do the insertion. To make sure one reader can not read more than 5 times. Here is my code,which is not working, the row can still be inserted without checking.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
BEFORE INSERT ON READING 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
      varReaderCount   Int;
      varRID           Int;
BEGIN
    varRID := :new.ReaderID;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO varReaderCount
    FROM Reading
    WHERE ReaderID = varRID;

    IF (varReaderCount >= 5) THEN
      BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('*************************************************');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The reader has reach the limitation of reading.');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('**************************************************');
      RETURN;
      END;
    END IF;
END;
```

I don't know why.

Comment: A trigger like this won't stop more than 5 sessions inserting rows - each session only sees the committed data, so the query will only return those rows which have been committed. You could have 100 sessions, all inserting rows without tripping up your trigger. (apart from the fact that your trigger doesn't do anything except dbms_output, which has already been pointed out)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the `INSERT` from completing, you need to `RAISE` an exception in your trigger. And by the way, those `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()` calls don't make any sense -- the trigger runs deep in the bowels of Oracle and there's nowhere to display that output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the lines :

```
IF (varReaderCount >= 5) THEN
    BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('*************************************************');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The reader has reach the limitation of reading.');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('**************************************************');
      RETURN;
    END;
END IF;
```

by the lines :

```
IF (varReaderCount >= 5) THEN  
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101,'limitation of reading');  
END IF;
```

After you need to catch the exception to avoid error during insert :

```
 DECLARE
    readingException EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(readingException, -20101);
 BEGIN 
    INSERT into READING VALUES (...);
 EXCEPTION
    WHEN readingException 
      THEN NULL;
 END;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I assume you have discovered, you cannot select from the same table that a row-level trigger is defined against; it causes a table mutating exception.

In order to properly create this validation using a trigger a procedure should be created to obtain user-specified locks so the validation can be correctly serialized in a multi-user environment.

```
PROCEDURE request_lock
  (p_lockname                     IN     VARCHAR2
  ,p_lockmode                     IN     INTEGER  DEFAULT dbms_lock.x_mode
  ,p_timeout                      IN     INTEGER  DEFAULT 60
  ,p_release_on_commit            IN     BOOLEAN  DEFAULT TRUE
  ,p_expiration_secs              IN     INTEGER  DEFAULT 600)
IS
  -- dbms_lock.allocate_unique issues implicit commit, so place in its own
  -- transaction so it does not affect the caller
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  l_lockhandle                   VARCHAR2(128);
  l_return                       NUMBER;
BEGIN
  dbms_lock.allocate_unique
    (lockname                       => p_lockname
    ,lockhandle                     => p_lockhandle
    ,expiration_secs                => p_expiration_secs);
  l_return := dbms_lock.request
    (lockhandle                     => l_lockhandle
    ,lockmode                       => p_lockmode
    ,timeout                        => p_timeout
    ,release_on_commit              => p_release_on_commit);
  IF    (l_return = 1) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'dbms_lock.request Timeout');
  ELSIF (l_return = 2) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'dbms_lock.request Deadlock');
  ELSIF (l_return = 3) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'dbms_lock.request Parameter Error');
  ELSIF (l_return = 5) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'dbms_lock.request Illegal Lock Handle');
  ELSIF (l_return not in (0,4)) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'dbms_lock.request Unknown Return Value ' || l_return);
  END IF;
  -- Must COMMIT an autonomous transaction
  COMMIT;
END request_lock;
```

This procedure can then be used in a compound trigger (assuming at least Oracle 11, this will need to be split into individual triggers in earlier versions)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER too_many_readings
  FOR INSERT OR UPDATE ON reading
  COMPOUND TRIGGER

  -- Table to hold identifiers of inserted/updated readers
  g_readerIDs sys.odcinumberlist;

BEFORE STATEMENT 
IS
BEGIN
-- Reset the internal reader table
 g_readerIDs := g_readerIDs();
END BEFORE STATEMENT; 

AFTER EACH ROW
IS
BEGIN
  -- Store the inserted/updated readers
  IF (  INSERTING
     OR (   UPDATING
        AND :new.readerID <> :old.readerID))
  THEN           
    g_readerIDs.EXTEND;
    g_readerIDs(g_readerIDs.LAST) := :new.readerID;
  END IF;
END AFTER EACH ROW;

AFTER STATEMENT
IS
  CURSOR csr_readers
  IS
    SELECT DISTINCT
           rid.column_value readerID
    FROM TABLE(g_readerIDs) rid
    ORDER BY rid.column_value;
  CURSOR csr_constraint_violations
    (p_readerID reading.readerID%TYPE)
  IS
    SELECT count(*) readings
    FROM reading rdg
    WHERE rdg.readerID = p_readerID
    HAVING count(*) > 5;
  r_constraint_violation csr_constraint_violations%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  -- Check if for any inserted/updated reading there exists more than 5 readings
  -- for the same reader. Serialise the constraint for each readerID so
  -- concurrent transactions do not affect each other
  FOR r_reader IN csr_readers LOOP
    request_lock('TOO_MANY_READINGS_' || r_reader.readerID);
    OPEN csr_constraint_violations(r_reader.readerID);
    FETCH csr_constraint_violations INTO r_constraint_violation;
    IF csr_constraint_violations%FOUND THEN
      CLOSE csr_constraint_violations;
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Reader ' || r_reader.readerID || ' has ' || r_constraint_violation.readings || ' readings');
    ELSE
      CLOSE csr_constraint_violations;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END AFTER STATEMENT;

END;
```